# Recurring and non-recurring payment in single checkout with paypal

Tags: paypal

Though this question has asked before. But there is not proper answer. That's why I post it again.

Is there any way to process Recurring and non-recurring items in single checkout with paypal ?

Comment: what do you mean by single checkout? need more information

Comment: single checkout means, both recurring items and non-recurring items in a single cart and they are processed to payment together.

Right now I have to process them in 2 times.